# Python "setup.py develop" why is my data package not available?

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a problem that I can't access my data package after setup.py develop. Here is my setup:

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from posixpath import join, relpath, normpath
import os

setup(
    name         = 'poc_datapath',
    version      = '1.0',
    package_dir  = { '' : 'target/python', 'resources' : 'target/res'},
    packages     = find_packages(where='target/python') + ['resources'],
    package_data = { 'resources' : [normpath(join(relpath(root.replace('\\','/'), 'target/res'),fn)) 
                                             for root, _, fnames in os.walk('target/res') for fn in fnames
                                             if not fn.endswith(".py")] },
)
```

Which generates a SOURCES.txt which look good to me, like that:

```
setup.py
target/res/__init__.py
target/res/resources1/resource.data
target/res/resources2/resource.data
target/python/poc_datapath.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
target/python/package1/__init__.py
target/python/package1/code.py
target/python/package2/__init__.py
target/python/package2/code.py
```

Accessing package1 and package2 works as expected, but I am not able to import the resources package. Why is that? It worked earlier with a similar configuration and a single data file, and no subfolders

[Edit]

Maybe I did not make this clear:
Doing `import resources` already fails, although there is an `__init__.py` in that folder.

Comment: You should use ``pkg_resources`` to load and access package resources in this case AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.py develop` just doesn't properly support package_dir, see https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/230

It won't work if the folder has a different name than the package (it does if they do).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `__init__.py` file inside each subfolder that you need to access. You already did that with packages 1 and 2.